# App relaunch on VoIP in iPhone

Tags: ios, push-notification, voip

I have implemented syncing feature using silent push , whenever app receive silent push I perform a network request and fetch the latest data. This is working fine in most of the cases, But if user killed the app , my app does not receive silent push notification.To overcome this issue I want to implement VoIP , will apple relaunch (in background) iOS app when it receive VoIP push even if user has killed the app ?

Comment: I think its possible as voip push can wake up App but  your app is non-voip app?.. might get rejected.

Comment: I will suport the VoIP feature. depending upone the flag I will perform syncing or process Voice call.